# Make a JPanel border with title like in Firefox

Tags: java, swing, firefox, jpanel, border

I would like to make an option dialog in my application. In this dialog I want to make kind of Areas surrounded with a border and with a title.

An example of what I want is in Firefox:

[image: Firefox Options]

How can I do something like that in Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) you can find all informations you need.

Basically you can use border factory to create a Border using types available in Swing:

```
Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(lineBorder);
```

You can also define your custom borders implementing [Border interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/border/Border.html).

Comment: +1 thats exactly what i was looking for. `BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
         loweredetched, "title");` thank you

Comment: for nicest output will be better look for CompoundBorder +1

Comment: @mKorbel: finally you are a 10k user :)

Comment: thanks, hmmm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498640/manage-gui-and-edt-in-mutli-task-application/7498808#7498808