# Align all gridbaglayout elements

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I want to make a Firefox like Option Dialog in Java with Swing.

I tried now to align all my elements on the north of the Window. I made it with the first element, but the next Elements are filling the room vertically and are not aligned.
For this i'm using the GridBagLayout.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


public class Background {  

    private Border headBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 8, 10, 8);
    private GridBagConstraints headPaneConstrain;
    private JPanel headPane;


    public Background() {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame dialog = new JFrame();

                //headPane
                dialog.add(headPane());

                //2 elements
                createSetting("test");
                createSetting("test2");

                //dialog settings
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                dialog.setSize(500,500);
                dialog.setVisible(true);                
            }
        });


    }

    private JPanel createSetting(String name) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(name));
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        headPane.add(panel,headPaneConstrain);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel headPane(){
      //Constrain
        headPaneConstrain = new GridBagConstraints();
        headPaneConstrain.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        headPaneConstrain.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        headPaneConstrain.weightx = 1.0;
        headPaneConstrain.weighty = 1.0;
        headPaneConstrain.gridx=0;

        //HeadPane
        headPane = new JPanel();
        headPane.setBorder(headBorder);
        headPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        return headPane;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
       new Background();  
    }  

}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What Firefox options dialog are you talking about? From your example I see nothing that would look like the options dialog I see on my firefox 7. Could you post a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500070/make-a-jpanel-border-with-title-like-in-firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want your " inner" panels to grow vertically, then why do you set `weigthy` to 1.0? You should set it to 0.0 instead (at least for all panels that should not grow vertically).

Besides, please pay attention that using borders will have an impact on alignments of components between 2 panels.

A better way to show different "sections" in a form is to use only one panel for the whole form and separate sections with a `Jlabel` followed by a horizontal `JSeparator`.

For this kind of form, I would use `DesignGridLayout` (rather than `GridBagLayout` which is too much of a PITA to get what you want...), but I'm biased here.

Comment: because with weighty of 0.0, the panel is aligned in the middle

Comment: in this case, you can simply add an empty panel at the end, with weighty = 1.0, it will take all the available space below the other panels.

Comment: is there a better way to do that?

Comment: if you go on using GridBagLayout, I don't think there is a better way to do that. You might consider using better layouts for what you want.

Answer (score 5):

this one can help you with that

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExpandingPanels extends MouseAdapter {

    private ActionPanel[] aps;
    private JPanel[] panels;

    public ExpandingPanels() {
        assembleActionPanels();
        assemblePanels();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        ActionPanel ap = (ActionPanel) e.getSource();
        if (ap.target.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            ap.toggleSelection();
            togglePanelVisibility(ap);
        }
    }

    private void togglePanelVisibility(ActionPanel ap) {
        int index = getPanelIndex(ap);
        if (panels[index].isShowing()) {
            panels[index].setVisible(false);
        } else {
            panels[index].setVisible(true);
        }
        ap.getParent().validate();
    }

    private int getPanelIndex(ActionPanel ap) {
        for (int j = 0; j < aps.length; j++) {
            if (ap == aps[j]) {
                return j;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void assembleActionPanels() {
        String[] ids = {"level 1", "level 2", "level 3", "level 4"};
        aps = new ActionPanel[ids.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < aps.length; j++) {
            aps[j] = new ActionPanel(ids[j], this);
        }
    }

    private void assemblePanels() {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 1, 2, 1);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        p1.add(new JButton("button 1"), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        p1.add(new JButton("button 2"), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        p1.add(new JButton("button 3"), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        p1.add(new JButton("button 4"), gbc);

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        p2.add(new JLabel("enter"), gbc);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        p2.add(new JTextField(8), gbc);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        p2.add(new JButton("button 1"), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        p2.add(new JButton("button 2"), gbc);

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(8, 12);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        p3.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));

        JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        addComponents(new JLabel("label 1"), new JTextField(12), p4, gbc);
        addComponents(new JLabel("label 2"), new JTextField(16), p4, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        p4.add(new JSlider(), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        p5.add(new JButton("button 1"), gbc);
        p5.add(new JButton("button 2"), gbc);
        p5.add(new JButton("button 3"), gbc);
        p5.add(new JButton("button 4"), gbc);
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        p4.add(p5, gbc);

        panels = new JPanel[]{p1, p2, p3, p4};
    }

    private void addComponents(Component c1, Component c2, Container c, GridBagConstraints gbc) {
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        c.add(c1, gbc);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        c.add(c2, gbc);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    }

    private JPanel getComponent() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 3, 0, 3);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        for (int j = 0; j < aps.length; j++) {
            panel.add(aps[j], gbc);
            panel.add(panels[j], gbc);
            panels[j].setVisible(false);
        }
        JLabel padding = new JLabel();
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        panel.add(padding, gbc);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ExpandingPanels test = new ExpandingPanels();
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new JScrollPane(test.getComponent()));
                f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(360, 360));
                f.setLocation(200, 100);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class ActionPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String text;
    private Font font;
    private boolean selected;
    private BufferedImage open, closed;
    public Rectangle target;
    final int OFFSET = 30,
            PAD = 5;

    ActionPanel(String text, MouseListener ml) {
        this.text = text;
        addMouseListener(ml);
        font = new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        selected = false;
        setBackground(new Color(10, 200, 220));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        createImages();
        setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
    }

    public void toggleSelection() {
        selected = !selected;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        if (selected) {
            g2.drawImage(open, PAD, 0, this);
        } else {
            g2.drawImage(closed, PAD, 0, this);
        }
        g2.setFont(font);
        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        LineMetrics lm = font.getLineMetrics(text, frc);
        float height = lm.getAscent() + lm.getDescent();
        float x = OFFSET;
        float y = (h + height) / 2 - lm.getDescent();
        g2.drawString(text, x, y);
    }

    private void createImages() {
        int w = 20;
        int h = getPreferredSize().height;
        target = new Rectangle(2, 0, 20, 18);
        open = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = open.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setPaint(getBackground());
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        int[] x = {2, w / 2, 18};
        int[] y = {4, 15, 4};
        Polygon p = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
        g2.setPaint(Color.green.brighter());
        g2.fill(p);
        g2.setPaint(Color.blue.brighter());
        g2.draw(p);
        g2.dispose();
        closed = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g2 = closed.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setPaint(getBackground());
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        x = new int[]{3, 13, 3};
        y = new int[]{4, h / 2, 16};
        p = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
        g2.setPaint(Color.red);
        g2.fill(p);
        g2.setPaint(Color.blue.brighter());
        g2.draw(p);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: in getComponents theres a JLabel `padding` there is the point (the same as jfpoilpret said in his second comment)