# JPanels with title

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jlabel

I have several JPanels that need to be displayed at the same time. They do display when I press the Port Settings button but I need there to be a title above each of the panels so the user will know which option they are selecting. My code as well as a screenshot is below.

```
package myGUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TestApplication implements ActionListener {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(3000, 3000);
    frame.setTitle("RBA Test Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    JButton select1 = new JButton("Select");
    JButton select2 = new JButton("Select");
    JButton select3 = new JButton("Select");
    JButton select4 = new JButton("Select");


    //Make the drop down lists
    String[] baudrates = {"57600", "115200", "128000", "256000"};
    JComboBox baudlist = new JComboBox(baudrates);

    String[] baudrates2 = {"57600", "115200", "128000", "256000"};
    JComboBox baudlist2 = new JComboBox(baudrates2);

    String[] bytesizes = {"7", "8"};
    JComboBox bytelist = new JComboBox(bytesizes);

    String[] bytesizes2 = {"7", "8"};
    JComboBox bytelist2 = new JComboBox(bytesizes2);

    String[] stopbit = {"1", "2"};
    JComboBox stoplist = new JComboBox(stopbit);

    String[] stopbit2 = {"1", "2"};
    JComboBox stoplist2 = new JComboBox(stopbit2);

    String[] flows = {"None", "Hardware","Xon", "Xoff"};
    JComboBox flowlist = new JComboBox(flows);

    String[] flows2 = {"None", "Hardware","Xon", "Xoff"};
    JComboBox flowlist2 = new JComboBox(flows2);

    String[] paritys = {"None", "Even", "Odd"};
    JComboBox paritylist = new JComboBox(paritys);

    String[] paritys2 = {"None", "Even", "Odd"};
    JComboBox paritylist2 = new JComboBox(paritys2);


    JLabel ipLabel = new JLabel("IP Address: ");
    JLabel connectLabel = new JLabel("Connect Time: ");
    JLabel sendLabel = new JLabel("Send Time Out: ");
    JLabel receiveLabel = new JLabel("Receive Time Out: ");
    JLabel portLabel = new JLabel("Port: ");
    JLabel baudrate = new JLabel("Baud Rate: ");
    JLabel bytesize = new JLabel("Byte Size: ");
    JLabel stopbits = new JLabel("Stop Bits: ");
    JLabel flow = new JLabel("Flow Con...: ");
    JLabel parity = new JLabel("Parity: ");
    JLabel stoLabel = new JLabel("Send Time Out: ");
    JLabel rtoLabel = new JLabel("Receive Time Out: ");
    JLabel portLabel2 = new JLabel("Port: ");
    JLabel baudrate2 = new JLabel("Baud Rate: ");
    JLabel bytesize2 = new JLabel("Byte Size: ");
    JLabel stopbits2 = new JLabel("Stop Bits: ");
    JLabel flow2 = new JLabel("Flow Con...: ");
    JLabel parity2 = new JLabel("Parity: ");
    JLabel stoLabel2 = new JLabel("Send Time Out: ");
    JLabel rtoLabel2 = new JLabel("Receive Time Out: ");
    JLabel portLabel3 = new JLabel("Port: ");
    JLabel vendor = new JLabel("Vendor ID: ");
    JLabel product = new JLabel("Product ID: ");
    JLabel stoLabel3 = new JLabel("Send Time Out: ");
    JLabel rtoLabel3 = new JLabel("Receive Time Out: ");

    JLabel logLabel = new JLabel("Input / Output Log");


    JTextField ip = new JTextField(10);
    ip.setText("192.168.0.102");

    JTextField ct = new JTextField(10);
    ct.setText("5000");

    JTextField rto = new JTextField(10);
    rto.setText("5000");

    JTextField sto = new JTextField(10);
    sto.setText("5000");

    JTextField port = new JTextField(10);
    port.setText("12000");

    JTextField sendto = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField reto = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField comport = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField sendto2 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField reto2 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField comport2 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField vendorid = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField productid = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField sendtime = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField receiveto = new JTextField(10);

    JTextArea logbox = new JTextArea() {
    @Override
       public java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(300, 450);
       };
    };

    logLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 3, 18));
    logLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    logLabel.setText("Input / Output Log");

    logbox.add(logLabel);



    //Add components to the panels
    final JPanel ethernetSettings = new JPanel();
    ethernetSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));
    ethernetSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    ethernetSettings.add(ipLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(ip);
    ethernetSettings.add(connectLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(ct);
    ethernetSettings.add(receiveLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(rto);
    ethernetSettings.add(sendLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(sto);
    ethernetSettings.add(portLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(port);
    ethernetSettings.add(select1);

    final JPanel usbHIDSettings = new JPanel();
    usbHIDSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
    usbHIDSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    usbHIDSettings.add(vendor);
    usbHIDSettings.add(vendorid);
    usbHIDSettings.add(product);
    usbHIDSettings.add(productid);
    usbHIDSettings.add(stoLabel3);
    usbHIDSettings.add(sendtime);
    usbHIDSettings.add(rtoLabel3);
    usbHIDSettings.add(receiveto);
    usbHIDSettings.add(select2);


    final JPanel usbCDCSettings = new JPanel();
    usbCDCSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 2));
    usbCDCSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    usbCDCSettings.add(baudrate2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(baudlist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(bytesize2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(bytelist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(stopbits2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(stoplist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(flow2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(flowlist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(parity2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(paritylist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(stoLabel2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(sendto2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(rtoLabel2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(reto2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(portLabel3);
    usbCDCSettings.add(comport2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(select3);


    final JPanel rsSettings = new JPanel();
    rsSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 2));
    rsSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    rsSettings.add(baudrate);
    rsSettings.add(baudlist2);
    rsSettings.add(bytesize);
    rsSettings.add(bytelist2);
    rsSettings.add(stopbits);
    rsSettings.add(stoplist2);
    rsSettings.add(flow);
    rsSettings.add(flowlist2);
    rsSettings.add(parity);
    rsSettings.add(paritylist2);
    rsSettings.add(stoLabel);
    rsSettings.add(sendto);
    rsSettings.add(rtoLabel);
    rsSettings.add(reto);
    rsSettings.add(portLabel2);
    rsSettings.add(comport);
    rsSettings.add(select4);

    final JPanel PortSettings = new JPanel();
    PortSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    PortSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    PortSettings.add(ethernetSettings);
    PortSettings.add(rsSettings);
    PortSettings.add(usbCDCSettings);
    PortSettings.add(usbHIDSettings);


    JButton portsettings = new JButton("Port Settings");
     portsettings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog port = new JDialog(frame);
                port.setTitle("Port Settings");
                port.setSize(400, 400);
                port.add(PortSettings);
                port.pack();
                port.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    JButton online = new JButton("Go Online");

    JButton offline = new JButton("Go Offline");

    JButton status = new JButton("Status");

    JButton reboot = new JButton("Reboot");


    JButton account = new JButton("Account");
     account.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog accountDialog = new JDialog(frame);
                accountDialog.setTitle("Account");
                accountDialog.setSize(400, 400);
                accountDialog.add(accountPanel);
                accountDialog.pack();
                accountDialog.setVisible(true);



            }
        });

    JButton amount = new JButton("Amount");
     amount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog amount2 = new JDialog(frame);
                amount2.setTitle("Amount");
                amount2.setSize(400, 400);
                amount2.add(amountPanel);
                amount2.pack();
                amount2.setVisible(true);



            }
        });

    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");


    JButton approvordecl = new JButton("Approve / Decline");
     approvordecl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog apprv = new JDialog(frame);
                apprv.setTitle("Approve / Decline");
                apprv.setSize(400, 400);
                apprv.add(apprvordecl);
                apprv.pack();
                apprv.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    JButton test = new JButton("Test Button #1");

    JButton testing = new JButton("Test Button #2");

    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Check Box");

    JCheckBox checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Check Box");


    ButtonGroup approvegroup = new ButtonGroup();
    approvegroup.add(apprve);
    approvegroup.add(decline);

    JPanel newButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    newButtonPanel.add(online);
    newButtonPanel.add(offline);
    newButtonPanel.add(status);
    newButtonPanel.add(reboot);
    newButtonPanel.add(account);
    newButtonPanel.add(amount);
    newButtonPanel.add(reset);
    newButtonPanel.add(approvordecl);
    newButtonPanel.add(logLabel);


    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
    testPanel.add(button);
    testPanel.add(button2);
    testPanel.add(checkbox2);

    JPanel posPanel = new JPanel();
    posPanel.add(test);
    posPanel.add(testing);
    posPanel.add(checkbox);

    JPanel llpPanel = new JPanel();
    llpPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    llpPanel.add(newButtonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    llpPanel.add(logLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    llpPanel.add(new JScrollPane(logbox), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(initialize);
    buttonPanel.add(connect);
    buttonPanel.add(disconnect);
    buttonPanel.add(shutdown);
    buttonPanel.add(portsettings);
    frame.add(buttonPanel);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("LLP", null, llpPanel, "Low Level Protocol");
    tabbedPane.addTab("POS",null, posPanel, "Point Of Sale");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Test", null, testPanel, "Test");

    JPanel tabsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tabsPanel.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.add(tabsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    frame.pack();



}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}






}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For titles on `JPanel`, you can use Title Border as below.

```
TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("YOUR_TITLE");
YOURPANEL.setBorder(title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a border above each of the panels like this example:

[Make a JPanel border with title like in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500070/make-a-jpanel-border-with-title-like-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("MyTitle"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set the title on the frame and not the panel. JPanels don't have titles, but their parent frames do.

Try this:

```
SwingUtilities.getRoot(yourPanel).setTitle("SomeTitle");
```

Comment: Please do read [How to use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)