# Java progress bar to work simultaneously work with application code

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, event-dispatch-thread

I am a beginner in java .So please let me know how can i simultaneously run the progress bar and my application code together.In other words i want to make my progressbar to increment as long as my application code is doing some processing.Please elaborate it with code.
    What i think is that i have to add two threads simultaneously.One thread updating the progressbar thread but i am not sure whether its the right way or not.
   i have written this code for incrementing progress bar (hard coded)

```
       class ProgressMonitor implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(true);
        //run untill 100% complete
        while (progress < 100) {
            //update the progressbar
            jProgressBar1.setValue(++progress);
            jProgressBar1.repaint();
            try {

                //Sleep for .25 second
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is basically that the long running task blocks the Event Dispatch Thread that updates the GUI.  One solution is to do the work in a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

> An abstract class to perform lengthy GUI-interaction tasks in a background thread. ..

See also the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) lesson of the tutorial for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is indeed to use a `SwingWorker`. If you want to use in in combination with a `JProgressBar`, I would recommend to take a look at the [`JProgressBar` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html), which has an example using `SwingWorker` in combination with `JProgressBar`. Or you do a quick search on this site and find examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916721/java-swing-update-label/8917565#8917565)

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about this and SwingWorker in this topic:

[Manage GUI and EDT in a multi-task application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498640/manage-gui-and-edt-in-a-multi-task-application)