# Loop is not continuous when using runnable thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have this small project that upon running the program it will automatically animate. In this case an oval shape should continuously animate using a thread. However in my program it will stop for the fifth direction - meaning following a certain path. Can anyone suggest me a better solution or help me let the oval shape continuously move until the user closes the program.

```
    package movingball;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class MovingBall extends JPanel{


    private int ballX = 30;
    private int ballY = 30;
    private int pattern = 1;
    private int limitHeight;
    private int limitWidth;
    boolean horizontalBoundary = true;
    boolean verticalBoundary = true;

    public MovingBall(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    public MovingBall(int x, int y){
        x = this.ballX;
        y = this.ballY;  
        repaint();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,700);

        MovingBall movingBall = new MovingBall();
        frame.add(movingBall);       
        frame.setVisible(true);

        BallUsingThread ball =  new BallUsingThread(movingBall);
        Thread first = new Thread(ball);

        first.start();

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics canvas){
        super.paintComponent(canvas);

        canvas.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 100, 100);
    }

    public void animateBall(){

        if(horizontalBoundary && verticalBoundary){
            if(pattern == 1){
               diagonalDown(getWidth()-100,365); 

            }else if(pattern == 2){
               diagonalDown(getWidth(),150); 
            }
        }
        if(!horizontalBoundary && !verticalBoundary){          
            diagonalDownLeft(150, getHeight());
            pattern = 4;             
        } 
        if(horizontalBoundary && !verticalBoundary){           
            if(pattern == 4){
                diagonalUp(0, 490);
            } 
            if(pattern == 5){
                System.out.print("helo");
                diagonalUp(500,10);
            }
            System.out.print("last move" + pattern);
        }
        if(!horizontalBoundary && verticalBoundary){
            diagonalUpRight(getWidth(),100);
            pattern = 5;
            System.out.print(pattern);
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void diagonalDown(int limitWidth, int limitHeight){
        this.limitWidth = limitWidth;
        this.limitHeight = limitHeight;

        if((ballX += 30) >= limitWidth){
            horizontalBoundary = false; 
        } 
        if((ballY += 30) >= limitHeight){
            verticalBoundary = false; 
        } 

    }
    public void diagonalUp(int limitWidth, int limitHeight){
        this.limitWidth = limitWidth;
        this.limitHeight = limitHeight;

        if((ballX -= 30) <= limitWidth) {
            horizontalBoundary = false;
        } 
        if((ballY -= 30) <= limitHeight){
            verticalBoundary = true;   
        } 
    }
    public void diagonalUpRight(int limitWidth, int limitHeight){
        this.limitWidth = limitWidth;
        this.limitHeight = limitHeight;

        if((ballX += 30) >= limitWidth) {
            horizontalBoundary = true;
        } 
        if((ballY -= 30) <= limitHeight){
            verticalBoundary = false;   
        }

    }
    public void diagonalDownLeft(int limitWidth, int limitHeight){
        this.limitWidth = limitWidth;
        this.limitHeight = limitHeight;

        if((ballX -= 30) <= limitWidth){
            horizontalBoundary = true;
        }
        if((ballY += 30) >= limitHeight){
            verticalBoundary = false;

        }
        //System.out.print("downleft");
    }

}

        class BallUsingThread implements Runnable{

        private final MovingBall movingBall;
        public BallUsingThread(MovingBall mb){
           movingBall = mb;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(;;){
                movingBall.animateBall();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.printf("Error",ex);
                }
            }      
        }   
    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551069/update-ui-using-swingworker-thread?rq=1

Comment: What happens in your code when `horizontalBoundary` and `verticalBoundary` both are true and `pattern` is 5?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem with loop, if you `System.out.println("loop running");` you will see that the loop is running, but that there is the problem with your draw ball logic that in this part of your code

```
if(!horizontalBoundary && verticalBoundary){
    diagonalUpRight(getWidth(),100);
    pattern = 5;
    System.out.print(pattern);
}
```

You are trying to `diagonalUpRight()` so after some calling to this method, then the none of the `if` clause will executed, because the conditions are not satisfied, so the ball remains in the same place at every loop, and seems that the loop stopped working.

**A small suggestion:** It is better to use `while(tru /*some condition*/)` loop instead of `for(;;)` in such cases.

**Solution:**  If you carefully check the logic you will see that there is no an `if` clause which is used for the condition below:

```
horizontalBoundary = true
verticalBoundary = true
```

When `pattern = 5` So when these two variables become `true` and`pattern = 5` then nothing will happen to the ball position, so you can write a condition which is used to check these two variables for `true` value.

**Eidt** Eidt the below part of you code and you will see the result which loop is not stopping, I just initialized the position of ball the values become `true` and the `pattern = 5`.

```
if(horizontalBoundary && verticalBoundary){
   if(pattern == 1){
        diagonalDown(getWidth()-100,365); 

    }else if(pattern == 2){
         diagonalDown(getWidth(),150); 
    } else { // added this else block
          ballX = 30;
          ballY = 30;
          pattern = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks whats the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

Override [paintComponent(Graphics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544549/how-does-paintcomponent-work) and implement all painting inside this method (but not animations).

Then use [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule periodic events each 100 ms, implement everything that *changes* the picture in the handler of this event and call `repaint()` from there at the end to refresh the picture.