# Is a swingWorker guaranteed to throw a state property change event on completion?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a class that takes in a number of `SwingWorkers` and runs them one at a time in a certain order. I use a `ReentrantLock` to make sure that only one worker runs at a time. Normally I would always unlock in a finally clause, but I need it to stay locked until the worker completes.

```
        nextWorker.getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener("state", 
        new PropertyChangeListener()
        {
           @Override
           public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
           {
              if (evt.getNewValue().equals(SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE))
              {
                 executionLock.unlock();
              }
           }
        });
```

If this is not the case, is done() guaranteed to be called? I would prefer not to call unlock this way, as it would violate encapsulation to some degree.

Due to the nature of the project it is likely that this will come up in a code review. In that case it would be helpful to have a verifiable source. So far I have been unable to find one.

Comment: +1 for nice described  and real question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- personally I tried everything possible with `SwingWorker`, but always ends me with `done()`, but I think that there no guarantee that implemented methods from `Future` ends correctly, still there this [Bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=da93fd119c93718375609ef367e25?bug_id=6880336)
- no idea about your code about lock/unlock another thread or process, but I suggest to use `Executor` for multithreading,
- how to get [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-thread) from `SwingWorker` Task
- personally I never ever had bad experiences with `SwingWorker` or some un-expected lack, but all `MultiThreading` Gurus told about `SwingWorker` for Production code never, there is still required use of `Runnable#Thread` instead of `SwingWorker`