# Differences between SwingWorker and Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am using SwingWorker to execute some heavy load tasks on an application I am making . Although today I got across the Executor class and this example :

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        someTask();     
  });
```

Can someone explain the reasons why one would use SwingWorker instead of the above example ? This is the way I am currently using SwingWorker :

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {            
protected Object doInBackground() {
    someTask();
return null;
}
};
worker.execute();
```

Comment: Check [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and you'll see that SwingWorker implements the Future<T> interface (and Runnable), which is returned from from an ExecutorService's `submit(...)` method. A SwingWorker has been built to interact well with the Swing event thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) `SwingWorker` is created as bridge betweens `Java Essentials Classes` and Swing by implements `Future`, and quite guarantee that outoput from methods `process`, `publish` and `done` will be on `EventDispatchThread`

2) you can invoke `SwingWorker` from `Executor`, this is most safiest methods how to create [multithreading in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171414/how-to-share-data-with-two2-swingworker-class-in-java) by implements `SwingWorker`

3) notice carefully with number or thread, because `Executor` doesn't care somehow about `SwingWorkers` life_cycle

4) another important [notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7679104/714968)

5) for listening states from `SwingWorker` you have to implements `PropertyChangeListener`

Answer (score 6):

The [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) has additional methods [`process()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process%28java.util.List%29) and [`done()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29) which are automatically executed in the event dispatch thread. This comes in handy if you plan to display your progress or final results in a user interface.