# Is it better to use done method or a change listener on SwingWorker?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingworker

I have a task that when done it update a swing GUI telling that is done. What I saw is that you can use `done()` method or attach a `PropertyChangeListener` and listen for the change to `done` status.

What is better to use and why? Or are they the same?

For example, this:

```
public class Foo implements PropertyChangeListener {

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

        if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())
                && (SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE.equals(evt.getNewValue()))) {

            this.updateTheGuiAndOtherThings();

        }

    }
}
```

or this:

```
public class W extends SwingWorker {

    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {...}

    protected void done() {
        otherClass.updateTheGuiAndOtherThings();
    }
}
```

In my case isn't necessary better efficiency, I ask more for correct code writing.

Comment: don't know good right answer to your question (problem is that there are combinations of two worst APIs in Java, Futore and SeingWorker together, both are unmanagable, without tracing, etc rest of flamewars), I'd be suggest don't to use event from PropertyChangeListener instead of done(),, to avoids a bugs to use publish/process or (use 2nd. bound property) setProgress

Comment: In my case isn't necessary better efficiency, I ask more for correct code writing. == use Runnable#Thread with invokeLater (just for methods implemented in Swing APIs) instead of shadowed, unmanagable SwingWorker

Comment: @mKorbel: I've heard of the bugs, but I've not run into them yet, and have used the propertchangelistener extensively with my SwingWorkers. One thing I make sure of doing is to call `get()` on my SwingWorker within the listener if listening for `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE` so that I can trap all thrown exceptions.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels but you're from another ... :-), Pete with all of my respect to your person, but I'm still think that Runnable#Thread with invokeLater is designated for production code, despite the fact that one of my code testing eight LotusDominos nodes run out of exception, three years, without restarting enviroment (from Solaris), and get() is really required +++,

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels and true is part of bugs is about get(), 2nd. about dynamic code generating important Java exceptions in doInBackground (I'm think that JVM is stopped curernt thread because thrown/throwable for JVM ended in get()) and 3rd. about overloading numbers of (possible) threads, a new concurently running instaces of SwingWorker from java.util.concurrent.Executor/Executors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Is it better to use done method or a change listener on SwingWorker?*

Generally speaking both ways are correct and equivalent.

However the main advantage of using `PropertyChangeListener` is you can have several listeners attached to the SwingWorker which allows you to split tasks in small code units rather than have a single `done()` block of code. This is useful for example if you have to update several Swing components and you want to keep those updates cohesively separate.

In addition using listeners reduces coupling between the SwingWorker and GUI components: it has no knowledge about what will happen when the background thread finishes and it's ok. By overriding `done()` method this won't be true anymore.

An important thing to do - when either listening for `StateValue.DONE` or overriding `done()` method - is to call `get()` method in order to catch and treat any exception that may be thrown during `doInBackground()` processing. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7053865/1795530) related to this point.

For the rest there is no major difference. I'd go with listeners just for scalability.

#### Update

Based on @mKorbel's comments below, you might want to take a look to this topic too: [Is a swingWorker guaranteed to throw a state property change event on completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7678841/1795530) and also even recosinder use a SwingWorker. I have had no problems personally but it's good to be aware about possible bugs related to the multi-threading nature of this matter.

Comment: Yep and 1+. I also like how using a listener reduces coupling since the SwingWorker now has to have absolutely no knowledge of the calling code while with the use of the `done()` method the opposite is true.

Comment: You are right, I've forgotten for minute about decoupling and separation of responsibilities. I'll add this point to my answer. Thanks! @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @dic19 PropertyChangeListener is only one notifier implemented for those two shadowing APIs SwingWOrker and Future, in this case (bound property implemented in SwingWorker) isn't notifier correct for distributing an events outside (long, repeatly and long buggy history), out of of SwingWorkers methods, by default execution of done() is end station (part of old bugs, fixed are about SwingWorker, occasionally, partially, never ended in done())

Comment: @mKorbel That's an interesting point :) Do you know if there are bugs in the notification chain of `DONE` state? Just this particular state, no the other ones. If so then using `PropertyChangeListener` wouldn't be advisable I suppose.

Comment: there were bugs for done(), then StateValue.DONE, about SwingWorker never ended in done(), then the event also StateValue.DONE doesn't ..., old bugs from Java6, never tested, because Oracle craped important part of bugs history for Swing last year, searching is possible only from Google and with a decent amount of luck for

Comment: Also mention to always call `get()` on the SwingWorker either in `done()` or in your PropertyChangeListener if listening for `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE`. This will help trap exceptions that may be thrown while the worker is running.

Comment: as a [reference for HFOEs good point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa)

Comment: @mKorbel Why would done not be called, under what conditions? Assuming doInBackground exits

Comment: @MadProgrammer (Why would done not be called, under what conditions?) exception or poor code design (one simple, short running, lightweight task) never terminated, pop_up from doInBackground,

Comment: @mKorbel I've never had an issue with `Exception`s, maybe `Error`, don't know.  Will check the short running tasks...Mind you, I'm now using Java 7/8

Comment: @MadProgrammer good point all bugs are Java6 rellated (flamewar - Swing in Java7/8 hasn't any bugs :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I just want to make sure as I'm using `SwingWorker` a lot...and Java 7/8 have there own bugs ;)