# Is MVC in Swing Thread Safe

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, layout-manager, jcomponent

I'm trying to touch limits of [MVC architecture](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html) in Swing, but as I tried everything all (from `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`) are done on EDT

my questions:

- is there some limits or strictly depends by order of the implementations 
  (wrapped into `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`) ?
- limited is if is JComponent#method Thread Safe or not ?
- essential characteristic of an MVC architecture in Swing, ?
- inc. Container Re-Layout ?

note: for my `SSCCE` I take one of great examples by `HFOE`, and maybe by holding this principes strictly isn't possible to create any EDT lack or GUI freeze

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MVC_ProgressBarThread {

    private MVC_ProgressBarThread() {
        MVC_View view = new MVC_View();
        MVC_Model model = new MVC_Model();
        MVC_Control control = new MVC_Control(view, model);
        view.setControl(control);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MVC_ProgressBarThread");
        frame.getContentPane().add(view);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MVC_ProgressBarThread mVC_ProgressBarThread = new MVC_ProgressBarThread();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MVC_View extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private MVC_Control control;
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    private JButton startActionButton = new JButton("Press Me and Run this Madness");
    private JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Nothing Special");

    public MVC_View() {
        startActionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttonActionPerformed();
            }
        });
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        startActionButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        buttonPanel.add(startActionButton);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myLabel.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));
        myLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(myLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void setControl(MVC_Control control) {
        this.control = control;
    }

    private void buttonActionPerformed() {
        if (control != null) {
            control.doButtonAction();
        }
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar.setValue(progress);
    }

    public void setProgressLabel(String label) {
        progressBar.setString(label);
    }

    public void setIconLabel(Icon icon) {
        myLabel.setIcon(icon);
    }

    public void start() {
        startActionButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void done() {
        startActionButton.setEnabled(true);
        setProgress(100);
        setProgressLabel("   Done !!!   ");
        setIconLabel(null);
    }
}

class MVC_Control {

    private MVC_View view;
    private MVC_Model model;

    public MVC_Control(final MVC_View view, final MVC_Model model) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
                if (MVC_Model.PROGRESS.equals(pce.getPropertyName())) {
                    view.setProgress((Integer) pce.getNewValue());
                }
                if (MVC_Model.PROGRESS1.equals(pce.getPropertyName())) {
                    view.setProgressLabel((String) pce.getNewValue());
                }
                if (MVC_Model.PROGRESS2.equals(pce.getPropertyName())) {
                    view.setIconLabel((Icon) pce.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void doButtonAction() {
        view.start();
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> swingworker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                model.reset();
                model.startSearch();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                view.done();
            }
        };
        swingworker.execute();
    }
}

class MVC_Model {

    public static final String PROGRESS = "progress";
    public static final String PROGRESS1 = "progress1";
    public static final String PROGRESS2 = "progress2";
    private static final int MAX = 11;
    private static final long SLEEP_DELAY = 1000;
    private int progress = 0;
    private String label = "Start";
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs1 = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs2 = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private final String[] petStrings = {"Bird", "Cat", "Dog",
        "Rabbit", "Pig", "Fish", "Horse", "Cow", "Bee", "Skunk"};
    private int index = 1;
    private Queue<Icon> iconQueue = new LinkedList<Icon>();
    private Icon icon = (UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        int oldProgress = this.progress;
        this.progress = progress;
        PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, PROGRESS,
                oldProgress, progress);
        pcs.firePropertyChange(evt);
    }

    public void setProgressLabel(String label) {
        String oldString = this.label;
        this.label = label;
        PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, PROGRESS1,
                oldString, label);
        pcs1.firePropertyChange(evt);
    }

    public void setIconLabel(Icon icon) {
        Icon oldIcon = this.icon;
        this.icon = icon;
        PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, PROGRESS2,
                oldIcon, icon);
        pcs2.firePropertyChange(evt);
    }

    public void reset() {
        setProgress(0);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        pcs1.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        pcs2.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void startSearch() {
        iconQueue.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
        iconQueue.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
        iconQueue.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"));
        iconQueue.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            int newValue = (100 * i) / MAX;
            setProgress(newValue);
            setProgressLabel(petStrings[index]);
            index = (index + 1) % petStrings.length;
            setIconLabel(nextIcon());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private Icon nextIcon() {
        Icon icon1 = iconQueue.peek();
        iconQueue.add(iconQueue.remove());
        return icon1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand your questions, I'd recommend cleaning it up a little but the short answer is no, Swing by design is not thread safe. I think you already know that so I'm not sure what the actual question is.

Comment: @mKorbel: Your question is not very clear: what does it do that is not correct?  How can we see the "lag" that we should see (should we?)? I ran the code and something looks broken (during the first two runs or so I can click the button and then it's grayed out while the progress is running but eventually I can click and launch the progress, yet access the button [Debian/Linux]) but I doubt it's the issue you're complaining about.

Comment: @mKorbel: you're modifying things on the EDT when you shouldn't.  Haven't you got it backward when you write: *"as I tried everything all (from SwingWorker or Runnable#Thread) are done on EDT"*  The point of *SwingWorker* is to perform lengthy operation **outside** the EDT.  I'm confused by that sentence of yours, need more infos : )

Comment: +1 for contrasting `String[] petStrings` with `Queue<Icon>`. Are you asking why this (intentionally) incorrect program doesn't fail more reliably?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is too long for a comment...

*First and this is unrelated to the rest of this answer: there are many different MVCs out there and the one you used in that piece of code you posted here is **not** the same as the one used in the article you linked to: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html*

The article correctly points out that it's just *"A common  MVC implementation"* (one where the view registers a listener listening to model changes).  Your implementation is a different type of MVC, where the controller registers a listener listening to model changes and then updates the view.

Not that there's anything wrong with that: there are a **lot** of different types of MVCs out there (*).

(Another little caveat...  Your view is aware of your controller in your example, which is a bit weird: there are other ways to do what you're doing without needing to "feed" the controller to the view like you do with your *setControl(...)* inside your *MVCView*.)

But anyway...  You're basically nearly always modifying the GUI from outside the EDT (which you shouldn't be doing):

```
public void setIconLabel(final Icon icon) {
   myLabel.setIcon(icon);
}
```

You can check it by adding this:

```
System.out.println("Are we on the EDT? " + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
```

This is because you're eventually doing these updates from your SwingWorker thread (the SwingWorker thread is run outside the EDT: it's basically the point of a Swing worker).

I'd rather update the GUI from the EDT, doing something like this:

```
public void setIconLabel(final Icon icon) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myLabel.setIcon(icon);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: (*) HVMC/PAC being my favorite(s) type(s) of MVC but I digress ; )

Comment: +1 for answer, 1) agreed that there are another MVC models, I follows better that I saw around (by Swing Guru - HFOE), 2) as I said - but as I tried everything all are done on EDT, 3) from Java1.6.021 is SwingWorker more stable but (all E.T. bugs are still in BugsDB http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6826514 and another), and if you'll override http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa , then output from done() is always in EDT, then there no reason for test that :-)

Comment: @user988052 hmmm Substance L&F required wrapping output to the invokeLater,