# Java EDT and Spawning Dialogues

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, joptionpane, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to learn the intricacies of Swing, and have read a great deal about the Event Dispatch Thread. I understand what is for, however am struggling with the following concept:

I have a JFrame which has been invoked in the normal way:

```
public class Controller {
GUITopLevel gui = new GUITopLevel(this);

public void initiate() {        
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    gui.init();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void menuCatch(JMenuItem eventSource) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gui.topLevelFrame, eventSource.getActionCommand());
}
}
```

I want to spawn JDialogs from the gui (code thus):

```
public class GUITopLevel implements FrontOfHouse {    
JFrame topLevelFrame;

Controller control;

GUITopLevel(Controller c) {
    control = c;
}

@Override
public void GUI() {        
    // Create an action
    MenuAction action = new MenuAction(control);

    // Create the Frame
    topLevelFrame = new JFrame();

    // Create the menu bar
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");

    JMenuItem file1 = new JMenuItem();
    JMenuItem file2 = new JMenuItem();
    JMenuItem file3 = new JMenuItem();

    JMenuItem edit1 = new JMenuItem();

    // Set the actions
    file1.setAction(action);
    file2.setAction(action);
    file3.setAction(action);
    edit1.setAction(action);

    // Add the menu items
    file.add(file1);
    file.add(file2);
    file.add(file3);

    edit.add(edit1);

    // Set the text
    file1.setText("Import Diagrams");
    file2.setText("Settings");
    file3.setText("Exit");
    edit1.setText("Cut");
    // Add the menus together
    menuBar.add(file);
    menuBar.add(edit);

    // Set size and add menu bar
    topLevelFrame.setSize(600,400);
    topLevelFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    topLevelFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void init() {
    GUI();
    //topLevelFrame.pack();
    topLevelFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

When a menuitem gets clicked, this is called in the controller:

```
public void menuCatch(JMenuItem eventSource) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gui.topLevelFrame, eventSource.getActionCommand());
 }
```

As `gui` is the parent container for the JOptionPane, and that has been created with an `invokeLater`, does this mean that the newly spawned JOptionPane has been called on the EDT or has it been called outside the EDT?

Apologies if this is a duplicate -- I can not seem to find an answer to this question.

Comment: It gets called on the EDT.

Comment: Thank you. So a call to append a JDialog to the `gui` outside of the thread will be dealt with on the EDT because that is where the `gui` has been created?

Comment: That is my understanding of it. If you want to separate the operation, you can work on one of the worker threads. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: Grand... I understand now -- worker threads are spawned for non-GUI work as I understand.

Comment: Worker threads are for Swing to avoid GUI lockup whenever you do something that takes a lot of processing. A simple popup operation doesn't really lock your GUI up though.

Comment: You're very welcome. I probably should have put this as an answer so you could accept it and close this question, but meh.

Answer (score 2):

Your question raises two critical issues:

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513) is typical, using `EventQueue.invokeLater()`. Note in particular that the `actionPerformed()` method of the `Timer` runs on the EDT. In contrast, your `GUITopLevel` appears to be instantiated on the initial thread, instead of in your `Runnable`.
- A modal dialog will block user input from other windows of the same application, but the EDT continues to run. In the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513), add a dialog to the `run()` method to see the effect.

  ```
  public void run() {
      ...
      f.setVisible(true);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dt, TITLE);
  }
  ```

See also this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) and this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8169964/230513) on MVC in Swing.

Comment: [maybe more ideas here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169964/is-mvc-in-swing-thread-safe)

Comment: Thank you. I used `swingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` to determine the TopLevelFrame is running on the EDT, and seems it is (returns true).