# addPropertyChangeListener() to JFrame from a JPanel on a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, propertychangelistener

I am creating a program with multiple tabs (JTabbedPane) in the tabs there is a JPanel with all my conent on. When I press start (JButton) I create a new instance of Task (a class that extends Swingworker ) and I want to set all my menuItems to enable(false). this is on a JFrame.

but I can't reach the JFrame from the Jpanel

Controller class:

```
public class Controller {
    private Task task;

    public Controller() {
        newTask();
    }

    public void newTask(){
        task = new Task();
    }

    public Task getTask() {
        return task;
    }
}
```

Frame class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private Controller controller;

    public Frame(String title, Controller controller) {
        super(title);
        this.controller = controller;
        controller.getTask().addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        TabbedPane0 tabbedPane0 = new TabbedPane0(controller);
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.add(tabbedPane0);
        tabbedPane.add(jPanel);
        add(tabbedPane);
        setSize(400, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        controller.getTask().TestPropertyChange();

    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName() == "changed") {
            System.out.println("Changed property, disabled all MenuItems that I added on this FRAME");
        }else if(evt.getPropertyName().equals("test")){
        System.out.println("Tested");
    }
    }
}
```

TabbedPane0 class:

```
public class TabbedPane0 extends JPanel {

    private Controller controller;

    public TabbedPane0(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        JButton  button = new JButton("Start");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                controller.newTask();
                /*My frame needs to be added to the TaskPropertyChangeListeners but I can't acces it*/
                controller.getTask().addPropertyChangeListener(Frame);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Task class:

```
public class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Task Is executed");
        return null;
    }

    public void TestPropertyChange(){
        firePropertyChange("test", null,null);
    }
}
```

Run class:

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        new Frame("StackOverFlow Example TabbedPane", controller);
    }
}
```

Comment: for example [MVC in Swing and PropertyChangeListener](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8169964/714968)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could just use this:

this gets my Parent JFrame where my JTabbedPane/Jpanel is added to

```
controller.getTask().addPropertyChangeListener((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(FolderCreatorTab.this));
```