# SwingWorker : illegal start of type

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

it is a piece of code that caused my problem :

```
   SwingWorker <Vector,void> sw=new SwingWorker <Vector,void>(){

     @Override
        protected Vector doInBackground() throws Exception {

             TvaJpaController tjc =new TvaJpaController(emf);
           Vector  l_tva=null;

          try{
         l_tva= (Vector) tjc.findTvaEntities();

             }
        catch(javax.persistence.PersistenceException e)
             {

             javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please check your internet connecting"); 

             } 
       return l_tva;
     }

     @Override
        protected void done() {
     Vector   l_tva=null;
            try {
                  l_tva=get();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

         int n =  l_tva.size();
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       Tva tva =(Tva)l_tva.elementAt(i);
   tva_article.addItem(tva.getIdtva());

   }

     }
   };

    sw.execute();
```

this line :

```
SwingWorker <Vector,void> sw=new SwingWorker <Vector,void>()
```

gives an error :illegal start of type...
I think my problem was due to "vector",but I do not know how to solve..
Any Helps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the problem is the use of `void`, which isn't a valid type argument. You can use `SwingWorker<Vector, Void>` though. (Note the difference between `void`, which is a Java keyword, and `Void` which refers to the `java.lang.Void` type.)

Personally I'd suggest using `List<E>` in preference to explicitly using `Vector`, and using it generically if possible, with `ArrayList<E>` as an implementation rather than `Vector`, but that's a separate matter - it's only the `void` / `Void` which is causing you immediate problems.

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi: What about it? That uses `Void` rather than `void` everywhere I can see.

Comment: Solved, SwingWorker<Vector, String> its work, but I do not understand what is the interest of second parameter, this is ridiculous ...

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi: It's not ridiculous - you just don't seem to have read my answer carefully enough: `void` is simply not a valid type argument. `Void` is, because that's the name of a type. `void` is *not* the name of a type, as such. You've tried `SwingWorker<Vector, String>` but did you try the suggestion frmo my answer of `SwingWorker<Vector, Void>`?

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi: Exactly. Do you understand now, and not regard it as ridiculous any more?

Answer (score 2):

and second issue is that about wrong usage of method `get()` into SwingWorker's `void done()`, because returns only exception from [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) (and only if exception exists), more about usage of method `get()` in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa)