# What causes com.sun.jdi.InvocationException?

Tags: java, swing

I'm getting a [`com.sun.jdi.InvocationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/InvocationException.html) when I return an empty `List<String>` from one method and set that empty `List` in another POJO.  This causes my `SwingWorker.doInBackground()` to not execute.

There's no stack trace and the JavaDocs don't even list a [`com.sun.jdi.InvocationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/InvocationException.html).  This seems completely anomalous.    Does anyone know what can cause this Exception?

Comment: What debugger are you using? Package com.sun.jdi is the core package of the Java Debugging Interface (JDI), it defines mirrors for values, types, and the target VirtualMachine itself - as well bootstrapping facilities. Excerpted from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/package-summary.html

Comment: I'm using the Eclipse debugger.  That doesn't explain why my doInBackground() doesn't get executed even when I don't run the debugger, though.

Comment: Agree, it does not explain why doInBackground() does not work but it does explain the source of the exception.  It is from the Java debugging interface.  Add the code for what you are trying to do in the background.

Comment: @Dean Schulze [you have to check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa)