# Java Task Progress Bars in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I need a very simple (skeletal) tutorial on progress bars for developing a GUI in Java. The progress bar can be "indeterminate" and ideally have an updateable text label.

Here is some skeletal code that I hope someone can expand upon just enough to get something working.

```
class MyFunView extends FrameView {

  // class vars and other stuff...

  @Action
  public void excitingButtonPressed() {

     /* I have n files to download */
     // Download file 1, set progress bar status to "downloading file 1"
     // ...
     // Download file n, set progress bar status to "downloading file 2"

  }

}
```

Basically, how and what do I wrap my download code in? (I understand there is some kind of subclass of Task required?)

Thanks much in advance.

EDIT:

We all only have so much precious time to be alive, and no approach can be done in as little code or time as I would have hoped, so I will not be using a progress bar.

Comment: *"I need a very simple (skeletal) tutorial on progress bars"* Here you go: [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). *"Here is some skeletal code that I hope someone can expand upon"*  What's your budget?

Comment: BTW - `downloading file..`  look to [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) for this.  It is made for it, and should give an indication of the real progress.

Comment: @B. VB. wrote in EDIT [We all only have so much precious time to be alive, and no approach can be done in as little code or time as I would have hoped, so I will not be using a progress bar.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm), because I think that you forgot to click ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need a very simple (skeletal) tutorial on progress bars for developing a GUI in Java.

- [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [examples here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm)

Comment: How did you come up with that stupendous list in that short amount of time?!?

Comment: No thanks needed.  My reward comes from seeing your answers. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) in conjunction with a [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).

The other alternative is to execute your task (e.g. `Runnable`) and periodically update the `JProgressBar`. Beware though, that in Swing any UI manipulations have to be done on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). `SwingWorker` has a nice property of taking care of this detail. Your own solution will have to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`,. for example:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        progressBar.setValue(progressCounter++);
    }
});
```

Lot of code for a stupid thing, isn't it? Maybe the `SwingWorker` with a `PropertyChangeListener` is a better solution in the end...

Comment: "_Lot of code for a stupid thing, isn't it?_" - Yup, so screw the progress bar.. not worth it, sorry users.

Comment: Well, it can still be in the `PrepertyChangeListener` - but with a different kind of boilerplate (the listener itself, no `invokeLater`).

Comment: @Anonymous I think that OP's needed to explaining [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10392153/714968) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10395968/714968), hell why there are only my up_votes