# How to catch specific thrown exception from Future?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, future

I've recently inherited some legacy code that makes heavy use of inner classes in order to implement threads. These inner classes make the current `JFrame` code monolithic and so I am in the midst of re-factoring the code in order to make use of the `SwingWorker` class.

My `SwingWorker` class makes a number of API calls to a webservice and then returns the result. Since this is asynchronous this is obviously best done within the thread. Currently the way the webservice works requires a few authentication calls to validate the request. These calls can obviously return errors. What I would like to do is throw a custom exception from within the `SwingWorker` if these webservice calls do not authenticate. Using the standard `Future` pattern I have code that looks similar to the following:

**SwingWorker (Background thread)**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
    if (!authenticationClient.authenticate(userid)) {
        throw new PlaceOrderException("Failed to authenticate client");
    }

    return orderClient.placeOrder( ... );
}
```

**Main GUI (EDT thread)**

```
// On the EDT
PlaceOrderWorker placeOrderWorker = new PlaceOrderWorker( ... ) {
    // This method is invoked when the worker is finished its task
    @Override
    protected void done(){
        try {
            String orderID = get();

            // Update some GUI elements using the orderID

        } catch(PlaceOrderException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please review your order", e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error placing order", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
catch(PlaceOrderException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please review your order", e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
}
```

as Java claims this exception is never thrown.

```
exception PlaceOrderException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

Now I know that calling `get` will cause the exceptions to be rethrown from the thread - and it can throw a `PlaceOrderException`. How can I catch this specific exception? The reason I have structured my code as such is that there are a number of exceptions that can be thrown in the background thread that I want the user to be prompted about via a `JDialog`. The reason I am declaring the `done` method within the main GUI class is that I need to instantiate the `JDialog`s from within the EDT thread. This allows me some nice decoupling.

Anyone know of a way for me to capture this specific exception with using `instanceof`? Or can you suggest a better pattern to use? Perhaps `SwingWorker` is the wrong choice?

Comment: Bit dirty: add `if (false) throw new PlaceOrderException();` to the try block

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7053865/230513).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catch `ExecutionException` and then investigate its cause:

```
    try {
        String orderID = get();

        // Update some GUI elements using the orderID

    } catch(ExecutionException e) {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause( );
        if ( cause instanceof PlaceOrderException )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
              this,
              "Please review your order",
              cause.getMessage(),
              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,
              null
            );
        }
        else
        {
          LOGGER.error("Error placing order", e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error placing order", e);
    }
```