# JTable in JScrollPane not displaying properly in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

The following code does not work on Mac OS X 10.6.8 but does on everything else I test, Mac OS X Lion and Windows 7.  The obvious explanation would be differences in Apple's java.  The table data does not show properly, if at all, on Mac.  Here is the code

```
package com.dramble.dance;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TableDemo extends JPanel {

    public TableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        TableModel tableModel = new TableModel();

        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);

        for(int i = 0 ; i <= 1900 ; i ++) {
            DataRow row = new DataRow(i,"Firstname"+i,"Lastname"+i);
            tableModel.appendRow(row);
            tableModel.fireTableRowsInserted(i, i);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TableDemo newContentPane = new TableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private class DataRow {
        private String fname, lname;
        private Integer id;
        public String getFname() {
            return fname;
        }
        public String getLname() {
            return lname;
        }
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public DataRow(Integer id, String fname, String lname) {
            super();
            this.fname = fname;
            this.lname = lname;
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    private class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        List<DataRow> data;
        private String[] columnNames = {"ID #","First Name","Last Name"};
        private Class[] columnTypes = {int.class, String.class, String.class};


        public TableModel() {
            this.data = new ArrayList<DataRow>();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return this.data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            DataRow dataRow = this.data.get(row);
            Object returnValue = null;

            switch (col) {
            case 0:
                returnValue = dataRow.getId();
                break;
            case 1:
                returnValue = dataRow.getFname();
                break;
            case 2:
                returnValue = dataRow.getLname();
                break;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        public void appendRow(DataRow row) {
            this.data.add(row);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
            return columnTypes[col];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the expected behavior as exhibited in Windows
[image: Working table on Windows]

Here is the same code on Mac OS X 10.6.8
[image: Broken on Mac OS X]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the AbstractTableModel, which came as a surprise to me for some reason, I figured it would be EDT and thread related for sure.  The problem is in my array for the `columnTypes` and using `int.class`.  Changing this to `Integer.class` fixed my issue.

Comment: +1 Interesting: The Mac UI delegate assumes a renderer for `int.class`, and `JTable` throws NPE on the first cell.

Answer (score 1):

Absent a complete example, it's hard to guess. What you have looks OK, but two thing stand out:

- I'm wary of `frame.setContentPane(newContentPane)`, which *replaces* the frame's content pane with your `TableDemo`. As `TableDemo` is a `JPanel`, it inherits a UI delegate that varies by platform. Instead, consider `frame.add(newContentPane)`, which *forwards* to the content pane.
- Your `appendRowData()` method in `DanceTableModel` should `fireTableRowsInserted()`, so callers can't forget to do so.

Comment: For this example code which recreates my issues, I copied a lot of code from a table demo from java, the replacing of the content frame is how they did it, I get the same issues on Mac no matter how I do it.

Comment: I decided to call `fireTableRowsInserted()` outside of `appendRowData()` because I will want to populate that table from a `SwingWorker` (since it will be so large and the data will be coming from the internet, it could take a while) and `fireTableRowsInserted()` needs to be called from the EDT correct?  So I will call it from the `process` method of the `SwingWorker`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the platform disparity you describe. Yes, `process()` runs on the EDT, where you _want_ the effect of firing the event.

Comment: I have the issue on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with java version 1.6.0_37.  When I test on a Lion machine, it works fine

Comment: Try this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7054627/230513). Edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem on 10.6.8/1.6.0_37, and add a [screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Comment: I see what you did there, amazing how making those sscce's leads to finding and solving your own issues, thanks a ton.