# Application is freezing when database is called

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, swing, freeze

I have lot of things implemented in `ComponentAdapter` of Java. Since it does loading data from database and displaying in `JTable`, I added it into another thread. I will show you one method which is being called by such `ComponentAdapter`

```
private class DisplayInitialRevenue_Thread implements Runnable
     {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            displayInitialRevenue_Method();
        }

     }

     private void displayInitialRevenue_Method()
     {
        //Get the dates from the combo
        String selectedCouple = revenueYearCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(selectedCouple.equals("Select Year"))
        {
            return;
        }

        String[] split = selectedCouple.split("/");


         //Related to DB
         double totalamountInvested;



             //Get data from the database
             dbConnector = new DBHandler();
             dbConnector.makeConnection();

             DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) initialRevenueTable.getModel();
             model.setRowCount(0);



             ResultSet selectAllDetails = dbConnector.selectAllDetails("SQL CODE HERE ");

             try
             {
                 if(selectAllDetails.isBeforeFirst()==false)
                 {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This table is empty");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     while(selectAllDetails.next())
                     {
                         String clientName = selectAllDetails.getString("Client Name");
                         String providerName = selectAllDetails.getString("Provider Name");
                         Double amountInvested = selectAllDetails.getDouble("Invest_Amount");


                        //Get Other Data


                         //Update the table
                         Object[]row = {dateS,clientName,providerName,amountInvested};

                         model.addRow(row);

                         //Get the total
                         amountInvested = amountInvested+amountInvested;

                     }

                     //Add the sum
                     Object[]blankRow = {null,null,null,null};
                     model.addRow(blankRow);

                      Object[]row = {dateS,clientName,providerName,amountInvested};
                 }
             }
             catch(SQLException sql)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sql.getLocalizedMessage());
             }
     }
```

And, this above thread can be called in 3 ways. That is by `ItemListener` attached to a `JComboBox`, `ActionListener` attached to a `JMenu`and `ComponentListener`.

**ComponentListener**

```
private class DisplayInitialRevenue extends ComponentAdapter
     {
         public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) 
         {
             formMemorizer = FormMemorizer.Initial_Revenue;
             //displayInitialRevenue_Method();

             DisplayInitialRevenue_Thread t = new DisplayInitialRevenue_Thread();
             t.run();
         }


     }
```

**ItemListener**

```
private class RevenueYearComboAction implements ItemListener
     {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                int selection = formMemorizer;

                if(selection==-1)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else if(selection==FormMemorizer.Initial_Revenue)
                {
                    //displayInitialRevenue_Method();
                    DisplayInitialRevenue_Thread t = new DisplayInitialRevenue_Thread();
                    t.run();
                }
        }
}
```

I have lot of these kind of methods to get the data from the database and feed the JTables and take data from GUI and save in database.

Now my question is, all of these are freezing sometimes, whenever a database call occurred. I thought it is bcs of Thread issue so I made the above `DisplayInitialRevenue_Thread` to call `displayInitialRevenue_Method()` as a test. Then I only invoked the area related to the call this method but it still freezes sometimes! My other database methods are not in separate threads, but this is method is, so why even calling "only" this method lead this to freeze? It is in a thread!

For side note, I am in Java 8, using MySQL Server version: 5.6.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) which comes with XAMPP.

Comment: please where it freeze, is there some JProfiler used, how, whats output from, but description talking about blocking an EDT, :-) Oracle tutorial - Event Dispatch Thread, my suggestion don't to use SwingWorker for production code,

Comment: voting to close as too broad

Comment: @mKorbel:In one of below answer says `Use SwingWorker`

Comment: @mKorbel: There is no place I can point, the freeze happen only "sometimes", and it happens "whatever time" the DB is called. Which means, there are lot of forms to edit,update,view records from DB, using any such form can lead this to freeze "sometimes".

Comment: @mKorbel `t.run();` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `t.start()` to start a new `Thread`, calling `Thread#run` does nothing more then calls the `run` method of the `Thread` within the same thread context...

Having said that, Swing is not thread safe, Swing requires that all updates to the UI are made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Instead of using a `Thread`, you should consider using a `SwingWorker`, which allows you to execute long running tasks in a background thread, but which provides easy to use `publish`/`process` methods and calls `done` when it completes, which are executed within the context of the EDT for you.

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: *"Please give me more advice"* - Don't do what you're doing, use a `SwingWorker`. You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: :-) don't to use SwingWorker for JDBC, is designated for enjoy

Comment: @mKorbel Why...?  With some tweaking (additional notification), I've found it actually rather useful ;) - Add a `ExecutorService` and it reduces the pain threshold considerably...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Imagine I am moving with `t.start()`. Some people are telling "don't update GUI using another Thread" ??

Comment: @sniper All updates to the UI will need to be synchronised to execute with the context of the EDT, if you don't want to use `SwingWorker`, you will need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` instead, which will highlight why I recommend `SwingWorker`

Comment: @MadProgrammer  ExecutorService & SwingWorker is one of uncachable, unmanagable bug, there isn't notifications, tracing from Future (one of black tunnels in Java), nor from SwingWorker, combination of ExecutorService & SwingWorker is about why my done() sometimes isn't called (overloading number of instances, or older instance ended faster than newer)

Comment: yes Runnable#Thread and invokeLater(just for methods implemented in Swing APIs, to notify GUI not whole process) is way to go

Comment: @mKorbel I've recently falling back on using the `PropertyChangeListener` support to provide (extended/customised) notifications (start/done) as well as a custom notification to the `publish` method to make it simpler to use...better then littering the code with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or using reflection (and, yes, I've done this). Sounds more like an issue with `ExecutorService`, never had a situation where `done` wasn't called, have seen issue where `get` wasn't and errors when unhandled, but that's a developer issue. All thread code adds complexity and breaks traceability...

Comment: @mKorbel And how unreadable `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` makes code, even tracing that is a pain :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer this forum loves SwingWorker, but my view is there isn't any reason for, I know that this is pure flamewar, and looks like as I'm the only one that (periodically) against usage of this unmanagable, shadowing API,

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater notify EDT, always if you want or not, if is there (and you know something about) some bug(s) then there isn't reason to use AWT/Swing for painting an GUI on the screen no longer

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Thanks a lot for the help. Marking this as the selected answer.

Comment: @mKorbel It's taken me a LONG time to figure out really how to use it, it's simpler to explain the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and getting information from one thread context to another it an easy and manageable fashion, but that's just my experience. I'd be interested to see actual case of where this fails

Comment: @MadProgrammer [I had playing with Executor & Runnable & SwingWorker, with real idiotic typo demonstrated in description and code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7053865/714968) (to test VMs on VMWare) on short periods (a few steps, separate threads, if is alive, how, where, who's, how many), sometimes I'm lost part of without seeing a connection on virtual machine (reading data from embeded db, then after db invoked a new test on local machine:-) too, JVM memory increased, never profiled, ran on separate lan,