# SwingWorker's done() method unexpected behaviour on disposing JDialog

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a `SwingWorker` class whose `doInBackground` executes queries on a remote database. I invoke `publish(true)` which sets `setVisible` to true for the JDialog holding a loader animation.

Everything is working fine as expected:

1. Background method starts.
2. JDialog modal is shown.
3. Background method completes.
4. JDialog is hidden/disposed in `done()` method.
5. UI is updated with database values.

However, when I point my application to the database running on my local machine the JDialog is shown but never closed/disposed even though the `done()` was called. This halts execution of UI code in the done method as well not until I manually close the loader dialog.

This odd behaviour is as follows:

1. Background method starts.
2. JDialog modal is shown.
3. Background method completes.
4. JDialog is **NOT** hidden/disposed in `done()` method.
5. UI is **NOT** updated

I must mention that execution over the remote database takes 10 seconds or more but a split second on my local database. How is the faster speed causing this odd behaviour?

Below is my code snippet:

```
    new SwingWorker<Void, Boolean>() {
        JDialog loader = new MyDialogLoader();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            publish(true);
    
            //DATABASE EXECUTION CODE IS HERE

            publish(false);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Boolean> chunks) {
            for (Boolean val : chunks) {
                loader.setVisible(val);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            loader.dispose();
            //UI UPDATE WITH DATABASE VALUES CODE HERE;
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: I wouldn't use publish and process for this purpose but rather a PropertyChangeListener

Comment: @gthanop It's really just that piece of code other than the JDBC code left out.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks. I will try implementing using PropertyChangeListener and provide feedback.

Comment: @user16320675 Thanks. I will give that a try too.

Comment: @gthanop the `SwingWorker` is implemented as an anonymous class inside `onClick` event of a button. But I get your point on the need of a reprex unfortunately, there is not much to to add to the code really. In a nuthsell the JDialog is not closing when targeting a local database but works as expected when I point to a remote (much much slower connection) database.

Comment: @Salim JB [maybe, you would need to fit with your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7053865/714968)

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is an Exception being thrown in `doBackground()`, so `publish(false)` is not being executed. Maybe an error accessing the database...

The Exceptions thrown by `doBackground` are silently caught and saved by the `SwingWorker`. The way to check if such an Exception was thrown, is to call the `get()` method in the `done()` method. It will throw an `ExecutionException` having the original exception as `cause`:

```
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        loader.dispose();
        try {
            get();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // some message or what ever using ex.getCause()
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // TODO
        }

        //UI UPDATE WITH DATABASE VALUES CODE HERE;
    }
```

Comment: No exceptions were thrown even after calling `get()` -- very odd. I've shared something that seems to have worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing this as the answer because it has solved the issue.

I did away with `publish` and `process` methods; the loader JDialog is now made visible from `doInBackground`. To ensure this UI interaction is performed on the Event Dispatch Thread, the statement is placed inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

```
new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        JDialog loader = new MyDialogLoader();
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                loader.setVisible(true);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                    });
    
            //DATABASE EXECUTION CODE IS HERE

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            loader.dispose();
            //UI UPDATE WITH DATABASE VALUES CODE HERE;
        }
    }.execute();
```