# Java Swing selecting a panel

Tags: java, swing

If I have a grid of 9 panels within another panel and I want to be able to click a subpanel and on click, send the content of that panel to a 'selected panel' area, how would I go about this? (Imagine a character select page for a videogame. When a player selects their character, it shows an expanded view of the character in a 'selected' pane)

I'm thinking of mouseListeners for each subpanel and retrieving the clicked component but I don't understand how I can copy that clicked component to a 'selected' area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your items to a `JList` or single-colum `JTable`. Add a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to your chosen component. Specify `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION`. In your `valueChanged()` handler, the `ListSelectionEvent` will tell you what value was selected. Use that information to fill in the fields of an adjacent panel. A complete example, illustrated below, is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25170471/230513).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was very helpful. My next step though, is to implement a whole panel (with it's own graphics2d inside it) instead of your icons but I don't know how to do this or in which part of your code my panel might fit

Comment: I'd suggest tinkering with the example cited; you might want to pose a new question based on any problems you encounter.