# Convert Graphics2D to ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing

Following from a previously asked question [Java Swing selecting a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476443/java-swing-selecting-a-panel/29479681?noredirect=1#comment47205219_29479681), I am trying to change the icons shown in the example to miniaturised Graphics2D objects.

My program will have several panels, each with a Graphics2D drawing in them, and on clicking a panel, an enlarged view will appear nearby (also as shown in the example from the other question's answer.

My issue now is generating a small icon from the Graphics2D drawing in each panel. Currently, I am having trouble creating the icon and using it.

```
public class BiomorphPanel extends JPanel{

PointCalc pc = new PointCalc();
private JLabel label = new JLabel();
private ImageIcon icon;

public JLabel getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public BiomorphPanel(){
    this.add(label);
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g){

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //g2d.scale(0.1, 0.1);
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(31, 31, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2dIcon = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();

    drawAll(g2d);
    drawAll(g2dIcon);

    g2dIcon.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2dIcon.fillRect(0, 0, 31, 31);
    g2dIcon.drawImage(img, null, 0, 0);
    icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    //icon = new ImageIcon(gra);
}

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {       
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     //scaling and translating to fit into mini panels in GUI
    // g2.scale(0.15, 0.15);
     //g2.translate(-100.0, 0.0);
     super.paintComponent(g2);
     doDrawing(g2);
    }    

 public ImageIcon getIcon(){
     return icon;
 }

 public void drawAll(Graphics2D g2d){
        //draw head
        Polygon hPoints = pc.getHeadPoints();
        g2d.drawPolygon(hPoints);

        //draw eyes
        Pair<Polygon, Polygon> ePoints = pc.getAllEyePoints();
        g2d.drawPolygon(ePoints.x);
        g2d.drawPolygon(ePoints.y);

        //draw eyebrows
        Pair<HashMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>, HashMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> ebPoints = pc.getEyebrowPoints();
        g2d.drawLine(ebPoints.x.get(0).x, ebPoints.x.get(0).y, ebPoints.x.get(1).x, ebPoints.x.get(1).y);
        g2d.drawLine(ebPoints.y.get(0).x, ebPoints.y.get(0).y, ebPoints.y.get(1).x, ebPoints.y.get(1).y);

        //draw nose
        HashMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> nPoints = pc.getNosePoints();
        g2d.drawLine(nPoints.get(0).x, nPoints.get(0).y, nPoints.get(1).x, nPoints.get(1).y);
        g2d.drawLine(nPoints.get(1).x, nPoints.get(1).y, nPoints.get(2).x, nPoints.get(2).y);

        //draw mouth
        Pair<HashMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>, HashMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> mPoints = pc.getMouthPoints();
        g2d.drawLine(mPoints.x.get(0).x, mPoints.x.get(0).y, mPoints.x.get(1).x, mPoints.x.get(1).y);
        g2d.drawLine(mPoints.x.get(1).x, mPoints.x.get(1).y, mPoints.x.get(2).x, mPoints.x.get(2).y);

        g2d.drawLine(mPoints.y.get(0).x, mPoints.y.get(0).y, mPoints.y.get(1).x, mPoints.y.get(1).y);
        g2d.drawLine(mPoints.y.get(1).x, mPoints.y.get(1).y, mPoints.y.get(2).x, mPoints.y.get(2).y);

 }

}
```

Above is where I try to create the ImageIcon.

```
public class ListDisplayPanel extends Component{

//private static final Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("html.pendingImage");

private ListPanel listPanel = new ListPanel();
private BiomorphPanel displayPanel1 = new BiomorphPanel();
private BiomorphPanel displayPanel2 = new BiomorphPanel();
private Icon icon = displayPanel1.getIcon();
private JPanel dpHold = new JPanel();

private class ListPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int N = 5;
    private DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList list = new JList(dlm);

    public ListPanel() {
        super(new GridLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
            String name = "Cell-" + String.format("%02d", i);
            dlm.addElement(name);
        }
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(N);
        list.setCellRenderer(new ListRenderer());
        list.addListSelectionListener(new SelectionHandler());
        this.add(list);
    }

    private class ListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                    list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(N, N, N, N));
            label.setIcon(icon);
            label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
            return label;
        }
    }

    private class SelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                displayPanel1.getLabel().setText((String) dlm.getElementAt(e.getLastIndex()));
                displayPanel2.getLabel().setText((String) dlm.getElementAt(e.getLastIndex()));
            }
        }
    }
}

private void display() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JSplitPane jsp = new JSplitPane();
    jsp.setLeftComponent(new JScrollPane(listPanel));
    JSplitPane jsp2 = new JSplitPane();
    jsp2.setTopComponent(displayPanel1);
    jsp2.setBottomComponent(displayPanel2);
    jsp.setRightComponent(jsp2);
    f.add(jsp);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->*/ {
        new ListDisplayPanel().display();
    };
}
}
```

And here is where I try to use the icon created. When I run the class, no icons appear for each 'cell' in the menu. Are the icons not created correctly or are they not used correctly? I cannot tell.

Thank you

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Your code does not compile.  Classes are missing and you try and use methods that aren't defined in the classes.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, unfortunately, my program was too large to include all the code here and I didn't know what MCVE or SSCCEs were. Thanks for reading, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to this is creating a class that implements the [`Icon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html) interface. Override the icon's [`paintIcon()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html#paintIcon-java.awt.Component-java.awt.Graphics-int-int-) method, which receives the suitable graphics context, and do your rendering there. Use the `Component` argument to retrieve properties and the `x` & `y` arguments to leverage the layout geometry. A complete example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513); more may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20implements%20icon).

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, Trashgod, I have the icons working now but when selecting an icon in the ListDisplayPanel, it disappears while selected. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I'm not sure; the selection color is specified by the Look & Feel; you may need to check that or save & restore the color in your code.