# Display multiple images

Tags: java, image, swing

I need to show images and images numbers are unknown - maybe 5 maybe 10 maybe more and I have no idea how I should display them.

This is my code and display only one image.

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\A-programmer-Life.jpg"));
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can load an image, create a label and add it to the frame, do that 5 times, and you'll have 5 images in the frame.

Comment: Try `JList`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25170471/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Display the images in a `JList`. The list will allow you to control the number of rows of images and then you add the list to a `JScrollPane` so scrollbars can appear if necessary.

You can add an `Icon` to the list and it will render as an image.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information.

The other option is to use a panel with a `GridLayout`. The labels will wrap to a new row when the first row is full. Again you would add this panel to a JScrollPane. The tutorial also has an example of using a GridLayout.