# The proper way to handle exceptions thrown by the SwingWorker.doInBackground

Tags: java, swing, exception, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

The proper way to handle exceptions thrown by the [`doInBackground`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground()) method of [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class is to invoke the [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get()) method from within the [`done`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done()) method, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524300/364056) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13942919/364056).

The documentation for the [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get()) method states the following:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.
>
> Note: calling `get` on the *Event Dispatch Thread* blocks *all*
>   events, including repaints, from being processed until this
>   `SwingWorker` is complete.

Therefore, if the `get` method causes a waiting within the `done` method, in fact it would block the Event Dispatch Thread, since the `done` method is executed on EDT.

However, after performing a simple test of the proposed solution, you may notice that the EDT is not blocked: this behavior occurs because the `get` method is invoked within the `done` method, so `get` is invoked after the result of the operation was calculated, and therefore the call to it will not block the EDT. Is this motivation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore, if the get method causes a waiting within the done method, in fact it would block the Event Dispatch Thread, since the done method is executed on EDT.

Actually, if done is called, the `doInBackground` has already returned, therefore calling `get` within `done` will NOT block the Event Dispatching Thread.

The same goes if you are using the `PropertyChangeListener` support and monitoring the change in state to `DONE`

**Updated**

So, after having a look at [SwingWorker calls 'done' before the 'doInBackground' is finished](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081474), which would mean that calling `get` on a cancelled worker would block the EDT indeventially, the basic work around is actually to ignore the return result by checking the `SwingWorker#isCancelled` state.  Let's face it, if the worker is cancelled, the return result is unknown/undefined, so it's best NOT to try and `get` it.

As an example (based on the code from the bug)

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SwingWorker<String, String> worker = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                try {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        System.out.println("Working...");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Got interrupted!");
                }

                try {
                    System.out.println("Cleaning up");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    System.out.println("Done cleaning");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Got interrupted second time!");
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                System.out.println("Done");
                if (!isCancelled()) {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    try {
                        get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("Took " + ((end - start) / 1000d));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Was cancelled");
                }
            }
        };

        worker.execute();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        worker.cancel(true);
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This may not hold if `cancel` is used. (bug) https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081474

Comment: @radiodef In theory, if cancelled, get "should" throw an InterruptedException. I'd be interested in knowingifnthis is just a bug in java 8 or not

Comment: I don't remember that much about the nature of the behavior, but I think it would be possible for `get` to block inside `done` if `cancel` is used. I encountered the bug on Java 6, so it's apparently been around for awhile. There's an older report as well. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6826514

Comment: @Radiodef: the description of [`done`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done()) method states that _you can query status inside the implementation of this method to determine the result of this task or whether this task has been cancelled_.

Comment: @Radiodef Shows how often I cancel a `SwingWorker`

Comment: @enzom83 Yes, the issue I'm referring to, raised in the bug report links, is that `done` may be called before `doInBackground` returns if `cancel(true)` is used. Thinking about it again, I suppose that `get` wouldn't block in this case, it will throw `CancellationException` (like MadProgrammer must be referring to above).

Comment: @Radiodef Having tested the code from the bug report, the simple "work around" is to check the state of the `SwingWorker#isCancelled` property in the `done` method, if it is, then the "return" value is unknown/undefined and should not be gotten, otherwise, you can inspect it.  As stated in the bug report response *"And to cancel the running task it should be canceleable i.e. be responsive to interruption"* - This would suggest that the Worker itself (in the `doInBackground` method) should be checking the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` or `isCancelled` state during it's work cycle

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void done()
{
    try
    {
        if(!super.isCancelled())
        {
            super.get();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```