# SwingWorker executes done() before finishing doInBackground()

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I have been reading about this, and from these posts, I get that I might be a bug

[SwingWorker, done() is executed before process() calls are finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958793/swingworker-done-is-executed-before-process-calls-are-finished)

[The proper way to handle exceptions thrown by the SwingWorker.doInBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445902/the-proper-way-to-handle-exceptions-thrown-by-the-swingworker-doinbackground)

However in my case, there is nothing that calls the done method. This is how my worker works.

```
public static class collectingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> { 


    collectingWorker(String name) {
        //initialize
        threadName = name; 
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {    

        loop = true;   
        while(loop){  
            //Code goes here
        }
        return null;
    }  

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        System.out.println("loop: " + loop);
        System.out.println("Collecting worker DONE");
        try {
            get();
        } catch (CancellationException x) {
            System.out.println("Cancelation");
            // ...
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            System.out.println("Interruption");
            // ...
        } catch (ExecutionException x) {
            System.out.println("Execution");
            System.out.println(x.getMessage());
            System.out.println(x.getCause());
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And on a separate thread, I have a counter that waits x minutes before setting loop to false. What I see is that collectingWorker done method is executed before the x minutes that it should have waited, and to make things worse, it is completely random, sometimes it works, sometimes it fails after 3 minutes, sometimes it fails after 90 minutes.

And this is what I get from the prints in the done method, as you can see, the boolean "loop" is never set to false

```
loop: true
Collecting worker DONE
Execution
java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

The logic nested within your while(loop) is throwing a NoSuchElementException causing your entire doInBackground() method to exit prematurely.