# Java Swing: SwingWorker uncaught exceptions are not getting picked up by Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, swing

My Swing program creates many threads and it's getting hard to handle exceptions properly. I would like to rely on a global exception handler, and i came across

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
```

Everything seemed to work fine, until i introduced a SwingWorker to perform a background task. Apparently, if an exception occurs inside my swing worker and it is not handled inside it, the exception will not be picked up by Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

This is a small snippet to test this behaviour:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwingWorkerAndDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    MyTask task = new MyTask();

    public SwingWorkerAndDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CentralizedExceptionHandler());
        task.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SwingWorkerAndDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            System.out.println("doInBackGround invoked");
            Integer i = null;
            System.out.println(i.doubleValue());
            System.out.println("This line is not reached");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            System.out.println("done invoked");
        }
    }

    public static class CentralizedExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("This line is not reached either");
        }
    }
```

Am i missing something here? Is there something i can set on my swingworker to behave as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.swing.SwingWorker#SwingWorker` is using a `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask` to execute the work provided in the method `doInBackground`.

In `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask#run` we can see that any exceptions are `caught`, and set as the result state of the `FutureTask` via `setException`:

```java
try {
    result = c.call();
    ran = true;
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    result = null;
    ran = false;
    setException(ex);
}
```

So in effect, this means that there are no uncaught exceptions bubbeling up from the executor Threads, and thus it's logical that your `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` is not used.

You're going to have to add your own exception handling to the worker, for that you can see the following references:

- [Graceful exception handling in Swing Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523623/graceful-exception-handling-in-swing-worker)
- [How should I handle exceptions when using SwingWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791223/how-should-i-handle-exceptions-when-using-swingworker)
- [The proper way to handle exceptions thrown by the SwingWorker.doInBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445902/the-proper-way-to-handle-exceptions-thrown-by-the-swingworker-doinbackground)
- [SwingWorker exceptions lost even when using wrapper classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941236/swingworker-exceptions-lost-even-when-using-wrapper-classes)

There are a few options from these references:

- directly handle the exception in your worker, or
- add a property change listener to check when the task is done; `javax.swing.SwingWorker#addPropertyChangeListener`
- and then retrieve the execution result of the task via `javax.swing.SwingWorker#get()` or `javax.swing.SwingWorker#get(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)`